# How to create a new array of objects containing the unique, with the sum of prices and quantity in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, object

I am trying to get a new array of objects from one with duplicats. 
For example this is the console.log of the array I have.

```
console.log(items);

[{
    _id: 5eb2f7efb5b8fa62bcd7db94,
    workName: 'best item ever',
    workTitle: 'this is the description',
    price: 300,
  },
  <Three objects with this id: 5eb2f7efb5b8fa62bcd7db94>
  {
    _id: 5eb19f3bad682508dc024301,
    workName: 'pack your gift',
    workTitle: 'best packaging for your gift',
    price: 5,
  },
  {
   <Two objects with this id: 5eb19f3bad682508dc024301>
  }]
```

How can I count the objects, sum the price and get an array of objects like the example below?

```
[{
    _id: 5eb2f7efb5b8fa62bcd7db94,
    workName: 'best item ever',
    workTitle: 'this is the description',
    price: 300,
    quantity: 3,
    totalPrice: 900
  },
  {
    _id: 5eb19f3bad682508dc024301,
    workName: 'pack your gift',
    workTitle: 'best packaging for your gift',
    price: 5,
    quantity: 2,
    totalPrice: 10
  }]
```

Here what I've tried, but I can't figure out how to create the new array mentioned above.

```
<all variables declaration>

if (cookies) {
        for (let key in cookies) {
            // create new array with works obj
            items.push(value.work = await Work.findById({ _id: cookies[key] }));

            // transform cookies obj in array with the values
            id.push(cookies[key]);
        }

        // give back an object where key is the array in input and the value is the number if the duplicates
        id.forEach(function (x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1; });
        let counter = 0;
        for (let i in counts) {
            counter += 1;
            totalPartial.push(items[counter].price * counts[i]);
        };

    }

    //swap object
    const newData = Object.keys(counts).reduce(async (obj, key) => {
        obj[counts[key]] = key;
        return obj;
    }, {});
    const total = totalPartial.reduce((partial_sum, a) => partial_sum + a, 0);
```

Comment: I would start with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) combination to group first the items. Based on that grouping you can increase the quantity and sum the price.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the count and sum of the duplicate id's like below:

```
var temp = {};
var obj = null;
for(var i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
   obj=cookies[i];

   if(!temp[obj._id]) {
      temp[obj._id] = obj;
      temp[obj._id].totalPrice = obj.price;
      temp[obj._id].quantity = 1;
   } else {
      temp[obj._id].totalPrice += obj.price;
      temp[obj._id].quantity++;
   }
}

var result = [];
for (var prop in temp) {
  result.push(temp[prop]);
}
```

You can more simplify the code but you got the point.

Check the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mrxctk)

**UPDATE**

You can use also the reduce and filter of the array

```
cookies.reduce((acc, val) => {
    var o = acc.filter(obj => obj._id == val._id).pop() || {...val, totalPrice:0, quantity: 0};
    o.totalPrice += val.price;
    o.quantity += 1;
    acc.push(o);
    return acc;
},[]).filter((itm, i, a) => i == a.indexOf(itm));
```

Comment: When you make a request from mongoDB _id is escaped, it's like _id: 5eb2f7efb5b8fa62bcd7db94 and not like the one you wrote _id: '5eb2f7efb5b8fa62bcd7db94'. In the DB the default field _id is a ObjectId, I guess it is possible to change in the model. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the first approach @ThemistoklisBogiatzoglou [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61753510), but in a more functional way.

Essentially you use an object as data structure to combine the items into common keys, then extract the values from the objects.

```js
const itemsMap = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const accItem = acc[item._id] || { quantity: 0, totalPrice: 0 }
  acc[item._id] = {
    ...item,
    quantity: accItem.quantity + 1,
    totalPrice: accItem.totalPrice + item.price
  }
  return acc
}, {})

const results = Object.values(itemsMap)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, it does not work because _id is an ObjectId. Any idea how to fix it? I guess I have to change something in the model when I'm creating the object in mongoDB, and tranform _id in string.

Comment: I think using `_id` as an `ObjectId` shouldn't be a problem. Where does it cause an issue for you? You can always do `item._id.toString()` or `\`${item._id}\`` to convert it to `String`. Or you can convert valid `String` to `ObjectId` using `new mongodb.ObjectID(somestring)`

Comment: It does not work. All of this methods don't work with the objects coming from mongoDB. I copid the console.log and created a variable with ' ' around _id and it works, just for testing.

Comment: Are you copying the value from somewhere to run the solutions? You should directly use it on a database response. Not on the data copied from a log or something. If you get `5eb2f7efb5b8fa62bcd7db94 `, what you should write is `new mongodb.ObjectID('5eb2f7efb5b8fa62bcd7db94')` to simulate the value coming from the database (or `mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5eb2f7efb5b8fa62bcd7db94')` if you use mongoose )

Comment: Sure, items.push(value.work = await Work.findById({ _id: cookies[key] })); Work is the model.  cookies[key] is the ID that I pass from the cookies. I also tryied with const works = await Work.find(); just for testing,

Comment: Can you add to the question how you construct `cookies`? I think the issue is that you have implemented the answer at an incorrect place. Also what does `value.work` do? I don't see a reference of `value` anywhere

Comment: I can't because it is not permitted to edit questions at my level. Btw as I wrote above I also tried directly from mongo without retriving data from the cookie with this works = await Work.find(); and it is not working.

Comment: I'm not sure where you have implemented my answer, it should be on the items array. If possible, put your code somewhere else and post a link to it.

Comment: This one it is not working, if I wrap the _id with  ' ' it works.

Comment: You are not using my answer, try my answer while using `works` as `items`

Comment: I tried and I get a very long console.log, this is the final part: '$locals': {},
    '$op': null,
    '$init': true,
    quantity: '[object Object]1',
    totalPrice: '[object Object]5     I've tried also with directly from the DB, no way.

Comment: `.find().lean()` instead of `.find()`

Comment: I got this back quantity: '[object Object]1',
    totalPrice: '[object Object]500'    Interesting, I'll read mongoDB documentation and I'll try to figure out what's going on. Thank you very much.

Comment: @I.Vacca It was a mistake from me. I have updated the answer, you can try again

Comment: Works perfectly! I'll put my head to understand what you did. Thanks again.